# How can you create spark edge with multiple attributes with scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-graphx

I have a csv file about flights with the following inforamtion in this order: flight date, flight number, origin airport id, origin airport name, origin state, destination airport id, dest airport name, dest state, distance, airtime

I have created a graph where nodes are airports identified by their ID and name and edges have the airtime as the attribute:

```
    case class Flight (Date:String, Flight_Num:Int, org_id:Long, Origin:String, Origin_State:String, dest_id:Long, Dest:String, Dest_State:String, Distance:Double, Airtime:Double)
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("FlightApp").setMaster("local").set("spark.executor.memory", "4g");
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
    def parseFlight(str: String): Flight = {
      val line = str.split(",")
      Flight(line(0), line(1).toInt, line(2).toLong, line(3), line(4), line(5).toLong, line(6), line(7), line(8).toDouble, line(9).toDouble)
      }
    val textRDD = sc.textFile("dataset.csv")
    val flightsRDD = textRDD.map(parseFlight).cache()
    val airports = flightsRDD.map(flight => (flight.org_id, flight.Origin)).distinct()
    val nowhere = "nowhere"
    val airportmap = airports.map{case ((org_id), name) => (org_id -> name) }.collect.toList.toMap
    val routes = flightsRDD.map(flight => ((flight.org_id, flight.dest_id), flight.Airtime)).distinct()
    val edges = routes.map{case ((org_id, dest_id), airtime) => Edge(org_id.toLong, dest_id.toLong, airtime)}
    val graph = Graph(airports, edges, nowhere)
```

I'd like to edit it so that the edges also have the flight date, number and the distance as their attributes on top of airtime, but am unsure as to how I can do that.

I have created an class to hold that information:

`case class EdgeWeights(FlightDate:String, FlightNumber:Int, Distance: Double, Airtime: Double)`

Currently traveling and can't test, shouldn't

```
val routes = flightsRDD.map(flight => ((flight.org_id, flight.dest_id), EdgeWeights(flight.Date, flight.Flight_Num, flight.Distance, flight.Airtime))).distinct()
val edges = routes.map{case ((org_id, dest_id), weights) => Edge(org_id.toLong, dest_id.toLong, EdgeWeights(weights.FlightDate, weights.FlightNumber, weights.Distance, weights.Airtime))}
```

work?
If so, can I then access the specific attributes for filtering and path finding algorytms by saying `edge.attr.Distance` for example?

Sorry if such questions are not allowed, my brain just wouldn't let me rest.

Comment: Can you please post example content of `"dataset.csv"`

Comment: each row looks as follows: `1997-01-01,980,10397,ATL,GA,10135,ABE,PA,692,188`, there is no header